# Send code to R from non R-files with the r-plugin in Vim

Tags: r, vim, keymapping

In OSX, how can I make a mapping in Vim to send code embedded in a non-R file to R for execution using the r-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate the [vim-r-plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) in any type of file, you may change temporarily the file type, because it's a [filetype](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_type_plugins) plugin. Assuming you are using OSX, you installed properly the *vim-r-plugin*, I was able to achieve this way from a markdown (`.md`) file:

1. In *Vim*, set your filetype as R: `:set ft=R`
2. Start *R* for this session: <kbd>localleader</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>
3. Select your code and press <kbd>space bar</kbd>
4. Optionally, revert to the original filetype `:set ft=markdown`

If you want the *vim-r-plugin* working permanently for a filetype, I suppose you will have to make some changes in the `~/.vim/ftdetect/r.vim`. Then create an appropriate file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`. Maybe, use the `~/.vim/ftplugin/r.vim` file as a model. I didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks. The key for me was `:set ft=R`. A now have the following mapping to send R code that I have as within `comment` environments in a TeX file to R: `nmap <Leader>rl :set ft=R<CR>\l:set ft=tex<CR>`

Comment: Are you trying to mix *LaTeX* code with *R* code? If yes, you should try to use the `.Rnw` name extension and add this file type in `~/.vim/ftdetect/r.vim`. Then you should use *Sweave* to render it (search *Sweave* in *vim-r-plugin* helper page). This should behave as for `.Rmd` files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows, there is a file [clip2r.js](https://batchfiles.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clip2r.js) in the [batchfiles](http://batchfiles.googlecode.com) distribution.

To install it, place it on your PATH and add the 2 lines in the comments at the top of the source to your `_vimrc` file.  It does not require any plugins.

To run it start gvim, enter some lines of R code, select them with the mouse and press F3 to send them to R.

Comment: And assuming MAC? See edit. This solution did not seem to work in IOSX.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work on other operating systems although you might be able to fashion something  yourself that does the same thing.  F3 sends the selected text to the clipboard and then it posistions itself in the main R window and performs a paste.